# Highcharts animate series on show

Tags: highcharts

I would like to show/hide chart series with a animation like the initial one, meaning that if on this

```
$(function () {
            $('#container').highcharts({

                series: [{
                    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
                }, {
                    data: [129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4]
                }]
            });


            // the button action
            var chart = $('#container').highcharts(),
                $button = $('#button');
            $button.click(function() {
                var series = chart.series[0];
                if (series.visible) {
                    series.hide();
                    $button.html('Show series');
                } else {
                    series.show();
                    $button.html('Hide series');
                }
            });
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pbohny/GvkPW/

I click hide/show, on show the series should animate(build up from left to right) like the initial animation.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not supported. You can try to get desired result by removing and adding that series back, see: http://jsfiddle.net/GvkPW/1/

```
// the button action
var flag = true;
var chart = $('#container').highcharts(),
    $button = $('#button');
$button.click(function() {
    var series = chart.get('1st');
    if (flag) {
        series.remove();
        $button.html('Show series');
    } else {
        chart.addSeries({
            id: '1st',
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        });
        $button.html('Hide series');
    }
    flag = !flag;
});
```

Comment: This works great for me, just need to write a bit more code. Thanks